# Combining inputs and math

Tags: python

I am trying to build a future value calculator using inputs but running into trouble with the math.  Can someone please advise on a solution?  Also, how could I convert the responses into integers or floats before calculating?

```
present= input("What is the present value?")
rate = input("What is the rate of return?")
periods = input("What is the number of periods?")
answer = {present} * (1 + {rate} ** {periods})
print(f"The  future value is", int(answer))
```

Comment: Why do you ask how the casting works: You do it already for `answer` in the last line of your code? As to the rest: Please show your attempts to solve it and point out where you are having problems.

Comment: Yes, the last line of code above was not working despite my attempt to include int which I think is what you mean by "casting".  I think that the key thing I was missing was that I need to convert inputs into numbers through the float or int function first.

Answer (score 0):

Just put float around them (a decimal number)

```
present= float(input("What is the present value?"))
rate = float(input("What is the rate of return?"))
periods = float(input("What is the number of periods?"))
answer = present * (1 + rate ** periods)
print(f"The  future value is", str(answer))
```

Answer (score 0):

- you can use `int()` to convert input into integer.

  ```
  present= int(input("What is the present value?"))
   rate =float( input("What is the rate of return?"))
   periods = int( input("What is the number of periods?"))

   answer = present * (1 + rate ** periods)

   print(f"The  future value is", int(answer))
  ```

Comment: this wouldn't work, since the rate would probably have a decimal in it and not be an integer

Comment: if rate is mentioned in decimal then we can convert input to float instead of integer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your inputs to numbers (either `float` or `int`) before doing math on them.  The curly-brace syntax isn't needed when you're doing math operations (in that context it's interpreted as a set literal, which is not what you want here), but it *is* used within f-strings to format variables as strings.

```
present= float(input("What is the present value?"))
rate = float(input("What is the rate of return?"))
periods = int(input("What is the number of periods?"))
answer = present * (1 + rate) ** periods
print(f"The  future value is {answer}")
```

(edit) also, I *think* you want to raise `(1 + rate)` to the power of `periods` rather than the way you had the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is that your formula for future value is incorrect. It should be pv*(1+r)^n, rather than pv*(1+r^n). This is assuming your rate (r) corresponds to the rate for each period.

Here some quick code that does what you are probably looking for:

```
pv = float(input("what is the pv? "))
r = float(input("what is the rate? "))
n = float(input("how many periods? "))

print("The future value is {}".format(pv*(1+r)**n))
```

Output:

```
what is the pv? 1
what is the rate? 0.05
how many periods? 10
The future value is 1.628894626777442
```